# Why does Loki look like he does in the movies?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel

Apologies for the slightly vague title.

It is revealed during Thor that

> Loki was taken as a baby and is actually the son of Laufey, king of the Frost Giants.

Is there any explanation as to why he doesn't look like the rest of his race?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a combination of his natural appearance, along with Odin's interference.  He was naturally born smaller than regular Frost Giants.  When Odin found him, he cast a spell on him to change his appearance to that of an Asgardian (there was a short flashback scene showing this in the film).  As he grew up, this spell seems to have maintained its power, even as he gained knowledge of Asgardian magic, so Odin must have made his spell hidden from Loki.  Otherwise, he would have noticed the spell on himself while he was mastering Asgardian magic.

During *Thor*, we only see his appearance change back to his natural blue skin when he's attacked by a Frost Giant's freezing touch or when he uses the [Casket of Ancient Winters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casket_of_Ancient_Winters#CoAW).  His appearance then changes back shortly afterwards.  It seems Odin's spell on Loki was extremely powerful.  It only ceases effect when Loki's Frost Giant nature is required, and only temporarily.  Loki doesn't seem to be capable of detecting the spell, and potentially is unable to remove the spell (although it's unclear if he would want it removed).

Comment: Minor nitpick: It's actually Aesir, not Asgardian. This always bugged me in SG-1 too. Though that Thor also uses "magic" to look more human. Go figure, eh?

Comment: @JohnO I'll have to rewatch Thor, but I could swear they're referred to as Asgardians at some point.

Comment: Possibly they were, but it's just the wrong terminology. The Norse deities belonged to two families, the Aesir and the Vanir. The ones most popular today are all Aesir, I believe. The realm that they inhabit is Asgard. Calling them Asgardians is like calling the English Englanders. It just sounds dumb.

Comment: @JohnO Stargate at least has the conceit that the Asgard (not Asgardians; the home of the Asgard was [Othala](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Othala_(planet))) were intentionally hiding their nature from a people that would not understand them

Comment: @JohnO: quite right. Acceptable terms for use by Americans when addressing the English are “Sir”, “Ma’am” and “Your Majesty”.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Quiet, Englander! Us civilized people are discussing important things, like comic books and comic book movies.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : you left out "sod" and "bloody wanker".

Comment: @JohnO I think there is a tag synonym you may want to install :)

Answer (score 11):

The best answer likely comes from the [mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki) from which the character is lifted from.

> In Norse mythology, Loki or Loptr is a god or jötunn (or both). Loki
>   is the son of Fárbauti and Laufey, and the brother of Helblindi and
>   Býleistr. By the jötunn Angrboða, Loki is the father of Hel, the wolf
>   Fenrir, and the world serpent Jörmungandr. By his wife Sigyn, Loki is
>   the father of Nari or Narfi. And with the stallion Svaðilfari as the
>   father, Loki gave birth—in the form of a mare—to the eight-legged
>   horse Sleipnir.

At Marvel's House of Ideas, [Loki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_%28comics%29) was descended from giants who were strong in magic use and innately magical beings. After a mortal conflict with Laufry (his mother in mythology, his father at Marvel) Odin saw the potential in the boy and took him as his own.

> After slaying the King of the Frost giants, [Laufey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laufey_%28comics%29), in battle, Odin
>   found a small Asgardian-sized child hidden within the primary
>   stronghold of the Frost Giants. The child was Loki, and Laufey kept
>   him hidden from his people, ashamed of his son's small size. Odin took
>   the boy because he showed strength when Odin slew his father in combat
>   and raised him as his son alongside his biological son Thor.

Loki is a trickster god and as many such deities is a shapechanger and powerful magic user. Likely, young Loki was shielded using the magics of Odin, but as he grew older and more skilled in magic, he was more than capable of rendering his appearance pleasing to the eye of whomever beheld him. Coupled with his smooth words and crafty demeanor, it was not long before he lived up to his name: Loki, Lord of Lies.

[image]

Comment: Basically, Loki is a shapeshifter and can look as he likes or as he thinks can be more useful to himself.

Comment: I thought about the fact that he is a shapeshifter, but it feels like that by the Avengers, at least, he has somewhat come to terms with his true parentage. Why would looking like an Asgardian be any more or less useful at this point? It also doesn't really explain why has not been blue up until this point. Was this Odin's doing?

Comment: @phantom42 The flashback scene in *Thor* where it shows Odin taking the baby Loki shows Odin changed his appearance from a Frost Giant's to a white Asgardian's.

Answer (score 5):

The only mention I see of why he looks that way in the Marvel Wiki is because when Odin adopted the boy, he lost his powers and gained that of the Asguardians, I'm assuming, thorugh Odin's power as All-father.

Comment: Cube was able to return his appearance back.. worth mentioning.

Comment: So does general appearance count as one of their "powers"?

Answer (score 3):

I had always assumed that Loki's taking of an Aesir's appearance was his own doing and not Odin's, since Loki is a renowned shapeshifter. I thought he was just using his magical power to more closely imitate what he saw, even as an infant. The movie never really made it clear, I guess. If it was Odin, I suppose that Loki was sort of locked out of his Jotun appearance in most cases, though he still seems to retain at least some of his Frost Giant power, like his ice knives. If it's Loki's doing, he may not have been consciously aware that he was taking a different form, since he'd been doing it for so long, and once he'd figured out that he was a Jotun, his hate of them would have compelled him to keep his Aesir visage. In the Avengers, I don't think Loki's truly come to terms with his parentage any more than he did in Thor, he's just being more open about it. He never seems very proud of it, mostly using it as an example of his differences from Thor.

Answer (score 3):

I've been studying Norse Mythology for some time now, and have found Loki (also known as Lopt, Lokka, Loke, Logathor) to be one of the most interesting, diverse and complex characters amongst the Gods.  His name dates back as one of the eldest Gods, along with Odin (woden) and Thor, aswell as Honir and Tyr.  Unfortunately he is often misrepresented, and common mistakes have been regularly made regarding him, the most common I've discovered are:

1. That he is full blooded Jotun - his mother Laufey was actually of the Aesir (Gods) so this makes him a Demi_god (Like Thor, who is also son of a Giantess)
2. That he orchestrated the death of Balder (there is no mention of this in the earlier texts, it is Hod (or Hodur, Hothur) who is responsible for the slaying of Balder)
3. That he fathered 3 monsters with a Giantess - an earlier text refers to this `giantess` who was a witch, the Gods killed her but she kept regenerating; spawning `3 monsters` - and it was Loki who killed her by destroying her heart.
4. He has also been confused with Logi - a fire Giant (because Loki is actually also God of Fire)
5. Finally his appearance - people assume that his association with fire means that he has red hair - but he's described in everal different sorces as being "Tall, long-legged, handsome, attractive, with blue/green eyes which change from one colour to the other" (it is Thor who has red hair, beard and even eyes)

Obviously Marvel do a fantastic job taking various concepts/ideas from the Norse Mythos.  So really his appearance in the movie could be due to a combination of all of the above suggestions - who is to know for sure?   :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Loki changed to the appearance of those who truly loved and accepted him. Maybe he thought that this Asgard doesn't come from a store...maybe, just maybe, this Asgard means a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it was Odin's spell, because he still looked Aesir when he was wearing the chains that supposedly suppressed his magic.