# Why does cartoon vs live-action Loki look so different?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki, thor-2011, marvel-what-if-2021

In Marvel's *What If...* series Episode 7 we see Thor who pretty much looks like his live action version, whereas Loki very much does not. Rather this Loki looks like other Frost Giants from *Thor (2011)* - blue and more than double the average human height.

What's the deal with Loki's appearance? Why does he look like a Frost Giant when live-action Loki looked human?

Comment: Semi-dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16234/why-does-loki-look-like-he-does-in-the-movies?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the start of the *What If...* episode, we learn that Odin never took Loki from Jotunheim, instead returning him to Laufey, whereas in the live-action film *Thor*, he appears to be using some sort of magical spell to convert Loki from a Frost Giant baby into an Asgardian baby.

The taller blue Loki is what he would have grown into without Odin's intervention.

Comment: But he was abandoned because he was a runt. So this explains why he's blue, but not why he's big.

Comment: @OrangeDog - I assume he ate his vitamins and worked out. He's quite buff.

Comment: @OrangeDog - We really only have Odin's word for it. *“In the aftermath of the battle, I went into the temple, and I found a baby. Small for a giant’s offspring—abandoned, suffering, left to die. Laufey’s son.”* - It's not really clear whether and why Loki was abandoned. His mother may simply have been killed in the battle or he was placed somewhere for safekeeping. We also only have Odin's word (coloured by his perception of himself as the hero in this little melodrama) that poor Loki was small and runty when he may have been perfectly normal sized for his age and race.