# Why was Loki so tall?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki, marvel-what-if-2021

In S1E7, *What If... Thor Were an Only Child?*, Loki appears as a regular-size (i.e. large) Frost Giant.

The difference in this reality is shown to be Odin returning the infant Loki instead of keeping him. However, Odin only found Loki because he had been abandoned for being a runt. So why does he still grow up to be a regular-sized Giant?

Comment: Dupe of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/254237/58193 ...?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot sort of. That's correct for why he is blue, but not for why he is big.

Comment: I think in this reality he was not abandoned just lost and Odin returned him. Occam's razor.

Comment: @OrangeDog well you know frost giants are big. The spell isn't in action, so he will become a "real" frost giant, hence blue and big.

Comment: I've closed it as a dupe. The spell evidently made him into an Asgardian. That includes not being as tall as a frost giant.